# Using hardware components in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android

Hey,
Sorry to bother you with such a silly question, but I can't find the answer myself.

I'd like to use hardware components in my applications (or: sensors), but it seems that I don't have the necessary files, as writing `import android.hardware.Sensors;` causes an error ("The ... cannot be resolved"). It is weird because I can import all other classes without any problem; I've downloaded the SDK. So what is wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

are you sure it isn't **import android.hardware.Sensor;** instead of **import android.hardware.Sensors;**

grtz

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right about it. I am currently trying to find a guide which deals with the current version of Sensor.

Answer (score 3):

Sensors information can be used with help of [`SensorManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

Comment: I copied the code written there: http://www.anddev.org/accessing_the_accelerometer-t499.html

Comment: It is an error there, there is no Sensors class, but there is Sensor instead.

Comment: I understand. Is there a guide suitable to the current SDK? Thanks.

Comment: what guide do you want? How to use it? Google's DevGuide is pretty good for that.

Comment: Are you sure such a guide exists on DevGuide? I don't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3):

You mean `import android.hardware.Sensor;`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html.

Comment: Well, I just copied the code from there: http://www.anddev.org/accessing_the_accelerometer-t499.html

Comment: That's from 2008. It has changed since then.

Comment: I see, thank you. Are you familiar with a good guide for the updated interface?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the API demos: if you look in <ANDROID SDK FOLDER>/samples/<ANDROID-VERSION>/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/Sensors.java that should have everything you need.

Comment: I'll look into it, even though when I run it on my emulator it gives me a force close... Thanks.

Comment: Emulator probably doesn't have real sensors. You'll need a device. Believe me when I say that debugging on a real device is WAY happier. Get yourself one of the low-end Android devices with no data plan and use that.

Comment: It also force closes on my G1... Thanks anyway.